# Spring Application Single Event and Multiple Listeners

Tags: spring, events

I have spring application which has an event publisher, which is publishing an event and application already have a listener for it. How do I introduce another listener for same event? Is it possible to have multiple listeners for one event? If yes how can I achieve it?

Comment: That is the whole point of sending an event. So yes, just write and register the listener as the other one and both will receive the event.

Comment: thanks, I was able to figure out.